# Aws::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, travis-ci, aws-code-deploy

I have a c# discord bot, which is on GitHub, and I'm trying to use Travis-ci to compile the app and send it to aws codedeploy where its them send down a pipeline onto my ec2 Linux instance and run. However, my build is failing with error:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Aws::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch)
```

I have followed the [docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/codedeploy/) pretty closely but I don't fully understand what went wrong.

This is the contents on my `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: csharp
solution: Melody.sln
mono: none
dotnet: 3.0.100
script:
  - dotnet restore
  - dotnet msbuild Melody.sln
deploy:
  - provider: s3
    access_key_id: "AKIAJZ4PYGPOWYHUP4VA"
    secret_access_key: &1
      secure: "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"
    on: &2
      branch: master
    bucket: melody
  - provider: codedeploy
    wait_until_deployed: true
    revision_type: github
    access_key_id: "AKIAJZ4PYGPOWYHUP4VA"
    secret_access_key: *1
    bucket: melody
    key: latest/Melody.zip
    bundle_type: zip
    application: Melody
    deployment_group: MelodyMusicGroup
    on: *2
    region: us-east-2
```

I'll also link to my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Atomization/Melody) and [Travis builds](https://travis-ci.com/Atomization/Melody) which provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! I feel kind of dumb... reading the docs I thought that I had to encrypt the same as they did; `travis encrypt --add deploy.secret_access_key`all I had to do was remove the `deploy.` from the string... not very clear on their part.